# Is it correct that a namespace prefix in a soap request be fixed?

Tags: soap, soap-client

When calling a web service, the client is expected to send a specific prefix for a namespace. Otherwise, a fault code is returned.

Here's the request that returns a fault code:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.connector.uut.cs.com.tr/">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <se:Security xmlns:se="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <se:UsernameToken>
        <se:Username>XXXX</se:Username>
        <se:Password>XXXX</se:Password>
    </se:UsernameToken>
    </se:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:kayitliKullaniciListeleExtended>
        <urun>EFATURA</urun>
        <gecmisEklensin></gecmisEklensin>
      </ser:kayitliKullaniciListeleExtended>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Whereas this request works:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.connector.uut.cs.com.tr/">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>XXXX</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>XXXX</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:kayitliKullaniciListeleExtended>
        <urun>EFATURA</urun>
        <gecmisEklensin></gecmisEklensin>
      </ser:kayitliKullaniciListeleExtended>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Only difference between the two requests is the namespace prefix (the one that works is wsse, every other prefix fails). Is it a correct implementation to ask the client to pass a specific prefix for the namespace?

I expected that the prefix names can be anything as long as the uri identified by xmlns: is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. The namespace matters, while the prefix can change. You can think to a namespace prefix like a "local variable".